# pythonの文法的な質問です。

Tags: python

- Input

```py
n = tuple or list
print(n)
```

- Output

```bash
<class 'tuple'>
```

これ、入力の時エラーが起きないのです。
つまり、文法的には間違っていないということですよね？
何が起きているのか解説お願いします。

Comment: お気持ちを嬉しく思います。プラス投票の権限を得られるのは信用度+15からですが、回答の承認で解決した気持ちが十分に伝わりますので大丈夫です。

Comment: 了解です。勝手がわからず、迷惑かけました。丁寧に教えてくださってありがとうございました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

文法上の`or`ブール演算(`A or B`)は、前者(A)が`True`の評価であればAをそのまま返します。
クラスなどは`None`でない限り`True`評価となりますので、ご質問のコードでは`tuple`が返っています。

**サンプルコード**

```
if tuple:
    print("ここは通る")

if None:
    print("ここは通らない")

print(tuple or list) # <class 'tuple'>
print(None or list)  # <class 'list'>
```

**参考資料**

- [Pythonのandとorはif文以外でも使える？andとorの動作が面白いという話をします](https://blog.pyq.jp/entry/python_kaiketsu_181016)
- [ブール演算 --- and, or, not](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)

Comment: 理解できました、ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

組み込みで `tuple` という名前のクラスがあるので、変数 `n` に class `tuple` が代入され、その文字列表現が `print` されています。

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple

Python のクラスはそれ自身もオブジェクトであり値として扱えて、変数に代入することもできます。

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

> As in Smalltalk, classes themselves are objects.